# Excel VBA ADODB DataType selection

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a data set in MS Excel 2013 which looks like this:

```
+------+------------+----------------+
| Name | DateWorked | HoursCompleted |
+------+------------+----------------+
| abc  | 03/01/2016 | 4:53           |
| abc  | 03/02/2016 | 5:22           |
| ghi  | 03/03/2016 | 2:10           |
| jkl  | 03/04/2016 | 5:30           |
| mno  | 03/05/2016 | 4:20           |
| pqr  | 03/06/2016 | 0:20           |
+------+------------+----------------+
```

where `Name` is string, `DateWorked` is mm/dd/yyyy, `HoursCompleted` is h:mm data type/format.

I am using ADODB to get some results out this data, storing it in a ADODB.Recordset and displaying in another sheet.

My code/query looks something like this:

```
countCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SUM([HoursCompleted]) FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Name] = 'abc' AND [DateWorked] BETWEEN #02/28/2016# AND #03/02/2016#"

Set countResults = countCommand.Execute
```

Now this works like a charm and gives me a result of `10:15`.

**However if the first value under `DateWorked` is NOT a `Date` datatype then I am not getting the result. For example, if my data looks like this:**

```
+------+------------+----------------+
| Name | DateWorked | HoursCompleted |
+------+------------+----------------+
| abc  | Not worked | 0:00           |
| abc  | 03/02/2016 | 5:22           |
| ghi  | 03/03/2016 | 2:10           |
| jkl  | 03/04/2016 | 5:30           |
| mno  | 03/05/2016 | 4:20           |
| pqr  | 03/06/2016 | 0:20           |
+------+------------+----------------+
```

How do I set the datatype for my columns?

Comment: Why is the data type not set to Date/Time? And is this an MS Access problem?

Comment: The datatype is determined by the first value under the header.. So in the second instance, DateWorked will be considered as a String because the first value is 'Not worked'.

Comment: OK. But is this purely an Excel problem? What database are you using?

Comment: This is all in Excel using VBA. No database.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it up, something like (select YOUR QUERY from (select * from XYZ where dateworked<>"Not Worked"))

Comment: What Shanka says about the first row under the column header is actually the way data connections to Excel work: that first row (or first few rows) determines the data type. One way to work around this is to have a "dummy" record in the first row with the correct data type. If you *know* that first record shouldn't be processed that shouldn't be a problem? The other way to approach this is to edit the connection string to use IMEX=1.

Comment: For reference, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/, http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.ch/2011/06/mixed-data-types-in-excel-column.html, http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/05/15/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595131/i-need-a-workaround-for-excel-guessing-data-types-problem

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and links. I applied the work around of inserting a dummy row with the correct data type as suggested by Cindy.