# Add decimal values to excel via ADO-connection

Tags: ruby, excel, decimal, ado, sequel

I have problems to add decimals to an existing excel file via sequel/ado.

I copy an existing excel file (`template = 'minimal_template.xlsx`) with two columns `col1` and `col2`, then I insert two decimals.

The result contains the data, but as strings:
[image: Excel Screenshot (German): The values are strings]

So my question: How can I add decimals as decimals to an Excel, when I use an ADO-connection?

Minimal example:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'fileutils'


template = 'minimal_template.xlsx'
targetfile = File.expand_path('result.xlsx')
FileUtils.copy(template, targetfile)
puts 'create %s' % targetfile

db = Sequel.ado(:conn_string=>"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=#{targetfile};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
target = db[db.tables.first]
target.insert([0.1, 0.2]) #add decimals.
```

Things I already tried:

- The columns in the template are already formated as numbers, but they become a String after the insertion.
- Using another way to create the xlsx (axls, roo...) is not possible in my use case. I must use an existing template.
- Using OLE to manipulate does is not possible (No excel installed)
- I can convert the format in Excel, but that's a manual process and I fear it will wrong, if somebody with another locale tries to convert the value.

I use Sequel 5.22, but I think it is no problem of Sequel.
In `sequel/adapters/ado/access.rb:111` the following SQL-command with decimals is called:

```
"INSERT INTO [Tabelle1$] VALUES (0.1, 0.2)"
```

So I guess it is a problem of ADO.

---

Update:
With a `puts db.schema(target).to_yaml` I get:

```
- - :col1
  - :allow_null: true
    :db_type: TEXT(255)
    :default: 
    :primary_key: false
    :type: :string
    :ado_type: 130
    :ruby_default: 
    :max_length: 255
- - :col2
  - :allow_null: true
    :db_type: TEXT(255)
    :default: 
    :primary_key: false
    :type: :string
    :ado_type: 130
    :ruby_default: 
    :max_length: 255
```

So the problem is really inside ADO. I tried to [use a schema.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55199150/676874), but without sucess

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307625/excel-vba-adodb-datatype-selection

Comment: @JordanRunning I have the opposite problem. I don't read, I write to the excel. I already defined the empty target cells as a number, but my ``insert`` adds only strings.

Comment: It seems to be the same problem, or at least a problem with the same root. From what I understand, ADO uses the actual values in the first few rows to guess the type. I'm not certain, but it seems likely that empty cells won't be considered in that determination.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I found a solution (but with an unwanted side effect).

Excel tries to guess, which data type a column has. If there are no data, the default is text255.

When I modify my template file and add an additional data line with entries with the correct value (here floating points), then the additional data are fine:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'fileutils'

template = 'minimal_template.xlsx'
targetfile = File.expand_path('result.xlsx')
FileUtils.copy(template, targetfile)
puts 'create %s' % targetfile

db = Sequel.ado(:conn_string=>"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=#{targetfile};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
target = db[db.tables.first]
#~ target.filter(col1: 0.1).delete #delete dummy line -> Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM.
target.insert([0.8, 0.9]) #add decimals.
```

Problem: I found up to now no possibility to delete the dummy line.

Just a side remark: I had once problem to load csv with long texts. All texts > 255 characters were truncated. I was able to solve this by adding test data on the 2nd line with long texts. Based on the 2nd line, Excel was setting the data type to the correct type and my texts on the following lines were not truncated.